# Positioning nodes within locations in D3

Tags: d3.js

How can I define locations within my SVG elements that contain nodes?
I'm trying to create an abstract map where nodes are contained within locations using D3. The nodes will then be linked to other nodes (sometimes many nodes in the same location +/or other locations).

So sample data may look something like this:

```
{"nodes":[
    {"id": "a", "location": "1"},
    {"id": "b", "location": "1"},
    {"id": "c", "location": "2"},
    {"id": "d", "location": "2"},
    {"id": "e", "location": "3"},
    {"id": "f", "location": "3"},
    {"id": "g", "location": "4"},
    {"id": "h", "location": "4"}]
}
```

I want to create 4 rectangles/bubbles, with 2 nodes (circles) in each.
I'm new to D3 and guess I'm struggling to go from simple datasets to JSON objects. So sorry if I'm missing the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating a force directed chart, you can use `forceX` and `forceY` to arrange the nodes in the screen. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#forceX):

> The x- and y-positioning forces push nodes towards a desired position along the given dimension with a configurable strength. The strength of the force is proportional to the one-dimensional distance between the node’s position and the target position.

In this demo, I'm taking your data array and positioning in the x coordinates according to `location`. First, I set an scale:

```
var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain([1, 2, 3, 4])
    .range([100, width - 100]);
```

And use this scale in `forceX`:

```
var force = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    .force('x', d3.forceX((d) => xScale(d.location)).strength(2))
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var data = [{
    "id": "a",
    "location": "1"
}, {
    "id": "b",
    "location": "1"
}, {
    "id": "c",
    "location": "2"
}, {
    "id": "d",
    "location": "2"
}, {
    "id": "e",
    "location": "3"
}, {
    "id": "f",
    "location": "3"
}, {
    "id": "g",
    "location": "4"
}, {
    "id": "h",
    "location": "4"
}];

var width = 500,
    height = 200;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var xScale = d3.scalePoint()
    .domain([1, 2, 3, 4])
    .range([100, width - 100]);

var circles = svg.selectAll(".bigCircles")
 .data(xScale.domain())
 .enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("cx", d=>xScale(d))
 .attr("cy", height/2)
 .attr("fill", d=>color(d))
 .attr("r", 40)
 .attr("opacity", 0.2);

var node = svg.selectAll(".circles")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", (d) => color(d.location));


var force = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    .force('x', d3.forceX((d) => xScale(d.location)).strength(2))
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(12));

force.nodes(data)
    .on('tick', function() {
        node
            .attr('transform', (d) => {
                return 'translate(' + (d.x) + ',' + (d.y) + ')';
            });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @gerardo, that looks like a great place to start. I wasn't sure if force directed was the way to go, but that seems to work nicely.

Comment: I thought you're trying to create a force directed chart in the first place. If that's not a force, the answer is even easier. So, please, explain exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Hi @Gerardo, sorry for the delay, I've been away for a bit. It doesn't have to be a force-directed graph, just a collection of linked nodes that are contained within larger parent nodes, with some different styles of links and some on-click functionality (i.e. click on a node and all links are highlighted).

Comment: Just to add it's for an information flow-type diagram.

Comment: @OliverHouston That being the case, post another question with that specification. If you ask here, in the comments, I'm the only one reading it. But if you post another question, everybody is gonna see it. Cheers.